# Missing data: not registered vs not available

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, phrase-meaning, academic-writing

I have a scientific paper table that has a few missing values. Values are missing as they were not recorded (written by a doctor) on patients' medical records. Should I address these values as "not registered" or "not available" or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> register = to put information, especially your name, into an official list or record
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/register)

To use *register* is to suggest two possibilities about the values.

First: they could not be registered because there was no information about them (they did not exist).

Second: there was information about the values but it was not registered, in which case readers might wonder why it had not been registered (did you make a value judgement? Are you biased? Were you selective?).

The reader cannot distinguish between these possibilities.

I therefore feel *register* is not what you are looking for.

If, on the other hand you say *not available* within the table, this is a plain statement that the required values did not exist **in a form that could be used for the paper**.

For these reasons I suggest that *not available* is acceptable and is the better of your two options.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in your question; you should address these values as *not recorded.*

Doctors use medical records to record things about the patient. Here are some example usages of the verb *record* as it relates to medical records:

> *More important for healthcare providers is that the courts tend to consider that if a medical decision, treatment or procedure is **not
> recorded** in the clinical notes then it has not been performed.*
> <sub>Source: [NCBI—How to keep good clinical
> records](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5297955/)</sub>

> *This process for making this type of correction can be as simple as just letting your doctor know that something was **recorded
> incorrectly** so your doctor can change it.*
>  <sub>Source:
> [Verrywell Health—How to Correct Errors in Your Medical
> Records](https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-to-correct-medical-record-errors-2615506)</sub>

> *When adding your more detailed note to the patient's record you should include your name, the date and time of your added note, your
> findings on examination and an explanation as to why these were **not
> recorded** at the time.*
>  <sub>Source: [MDU—Amending patient
> records](https://www.themdu.com/guidance-and-advice/guides/ethical-dilemmas/amending-patient-records)</sub>